# Pass radio button values to component as Form data on Form Submit in Angular2

Tags: forms, angular

1. Html template below

```html
<form class="form" #pubForm="ngForm">
        
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Publisher Name:</label>
        <input type="text" #name id="name" ngControl="name" #name="ngForm" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" style="width:50%;" required maxlength="50">
        <div *ngIf="name.touched && name.errors">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="name.errors.required" style="width:50%;">
                Name is Required (Maxlength is 50 characters)
            </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="status">Status:</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="options" (click)="model.options = 'active'" [checked]="'active' === model.options">Active
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="options" (click)="model.options = 'inactive'" [checked]="'inactive' === model.options">Inactive
        </label>  
      </div>
      
     <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="onSubmit(pubForm.value)">Submit</button>
        <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </div>  

</form>
```

2. Component code below

```js
model = { options: 'active' }; 

onSubmit(form:any) : void {
  form.status = this.model.options; 
  console.log(form);    
}
```

On console log now I get object on form submit but I want to pass radio button value as name input box value is passed automatically on form submit in my form above. How to do pass radio button selection as form data ? The input name above is being passed automatically on click of Submit.

Comment: I think this should work like for other input elements in the next version (RC.5)

Comment: So right now I have to continue doing what I am doing. Ok. :-|. Its in 2.0.0-rc.4 (2016-06-30) as of now.

Comment: I expect RC.5 to be released any day. Usually Wednesday is release day ;-)